# Lottie Animation not working on IOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, lottie

I am using Lottie for animation in Xamarin Forms app. The animation works fine on Android but the animation doesn't shows up on iOS.

I have intialized AnimationViewRenderer in AppDelegate and using v2.4.0.Also, I have tried setting Auto Play mode manually from code behind, it didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Well seems like their is problem with the v2.4.0, downgraded to 2.3.4 and it worked like a charm.